# Use IdentityServer4 to control access to different methods in the same WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

[Ideal effect flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoaut.png)

For the current understanding of IdentityServer4, I found that the basic interface permission configuration is more suitable for permission control projects with multiple WebApi
However, the current project requirement is to authorize different interfaces in the same WebApi that can be automatically generated later.
Can IdentityServer meet this requirement?
If it can be done, is there a similar demo?
Above I put a rough expected flow chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement modern authorization I would recommend that you use the built in Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core.

This allows you to decouple the authorization rules from the actual API-controllers and action methods in your API, like this picture tries to show:

[image]

See this link for examples

- [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)